# Converting .rtf to .doc/.dox with a service

Tags: mac, automator, textedit

I like to write in rich text with textedit and then do more complicated formatting tasks with Pages 5.0. However, Pages doesn't open rich text. To get the text into pages I either have to copy and paste, or laboriously duplicate the file in textedit and save it as .doc/docx. On top of that, I then have re-save to file in the .pages format to be able to edit it with Pages.

What I would like is a simple automator workflow to save the foremost textedit .rtf file to a .doc/.docx format, which can then be opened by Pages and saved to the .pages format.

I think there is a built-in program called textutil which could be used in the workflow.

Comment: Print to PDF, open PDF in Pages?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a wrapper of the textutil utility. Download this workflow to convert various file types. It's very useful when converting in batches. Download it from the below address.

http://automatorworld.com/download/convert-text.zip

Comment: This link doesn't work any more...

Answer (score -2):

I use [Convertio.co](https://convertio.co/rtf-doc/) to convert RTF to DOC files. It's a free online service you might want to try it and see what you get.

Comment: How would you integrate this into an Automator workflow?